# daterangeinput without fluidpage in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, daterangepicker

I have an issue while creating a shiny web app using semantic.dashboard library.

Below is the code for my app.

```
library(semantic.dashboard)

# Define UI
header <- dashboardHeader(
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    side = "left",
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(tabName = "overview", text = "Overview", icon = icon("home")),
        menuItem(tabName = "analysis", text = "Analysis", icon = icon("chart bar"))
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    dateRangeInput("datepicker", NULL, start = Sys.Date()-30, end = Sys.Date()-1)
)

tabItems(
  tabItem(
    tabName = "overview",
    fluidRow(

    )
  ),
  tabItem(
    tabName = "analysis",
    fluidRow(

    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body,
  title = "My Dashboard",
  theme = "lumen"
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The result is in the screenshot below:

[image: results]

The main problem is that the dates inside the daterangeinput widget are just like simple text inside textbox.
I can't click on them to change the dates.

Using fluidPage() would resolve the problem, but the whole web page isn't filled totally by the app (and for this app, responsiveness isn't really useful).

Below is the screenshot of the app when I use fluidPage(), you can see that there's so much space between the sidebar and the border, and beetween the sidebar and the body.

[app with fluidPage()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRwce.png)

I'd like to know if it's possible to use daterangeinput without using fluidPage() or, if not possible, know how to remove the padding between the border and the sidebar when using fluidPage.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "my daterange picker is not" - it looks as if you didn't finish writing and it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for your remark. I've edited the post, so I think it's clearer now.

Comment: Yep. Much better. :)

Comment: I think it is some compatibility issue with semantic.dashboard not supporting daterangepicker. When I change the library to shinydashboard, and comment out (theme=lumen) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Above example doesn't work because it uses bootstrap framework styles - contrary to `shiny.semantic` or `semantic.dashboard` packages.

Please check my [PR](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.semantic/pull/99) to `shiny.semantic` package. I've implemented there simple date input with usage of semantic-ui components. You can also use it to create simple date range (added quick example in PR).

Comment: Great, thanks Krystian. I'll try this out right now.